# Существует ли API для русского stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Собственно, сабж.

На большом se в списке сайтов я не нашел ru.stackoverflow.com. Может плохо искал?

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true

Comment: В дополнение к овтету, [небольшой пример использования API для Stack Overflow на русском](http://chabanovsky.com/2015/09/stackexchange-api-for-communities/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Exchange API работает для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange. Чтобы получить информатию с этого сайта, нужен параметр `site=ru.stackoverflow`. Например:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=ru.stackoverflow&run=true

А в списке Вы его не нашли, потому что по умолчанию API возвращает до 20 результатов (а сайтов больше 150). Чтобы получить полный список через метод `/sites` нужно установить `pagesize=1000` для верности. (Это единственный метод, который не ограничивает значения `pagesize`: для прочих методов страница не может превышать 100 результатов.)

Comment: В запросах со списками также передается поле `has_more`, по нему можно понять остались ли еще данные. Для того, что получить много элементов, больше, чем возможно за один запрос, нужно передавать в url параметр `page` и с каждым запросом увеличивать на 1, пока в возвращаемом ответе `has_more=true`. Первый запрос, соответственно, начинается с `page=1`.